# Using Jackson's @JsonTypeInfo with a custom serializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm running into a problem with Jackson where it does not respect the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotations when I use a custom serializer.  The simplified example below does not require the custom serialization and outputs the `type` property as expected when I don't use the custom serializer.  However, once the custom serializer has been enabled, the `type` property is not written and prevents deserialization.  This is a test case for my actual system, which does require a custom serializer and, if it makes a difference, is attempting to serialize a `Map<Enum, Map<Enum, T>>` where `T` is the polymorphic class whose type information is not being written.  How can I write the custom serializer so it correctly handles the type information?  I'm hoping that if I can get it working for the test case below, I will be able to apply the same concepts to the actual code.

The test program attempts to simulate as closely as possible the serialization process I'm using in the real application, building a `Map<>` and serializing that instead of serializing the `Zoo` directly.

Expected Output:

```
{
    "Spike": {
        "type": "dog",
        "name": "Spike",
        "breed": "mutt",
        "leashColor": "red"
    },
    "Fluffy": {
        "type": "cat",
        "name": "Fluffy",
        "favoriteToy": "spider ring"
    }
}
```

By commenting out the custom serializer registration in the `SimpleModule` you can see the type information is output, but with the serializer registered, the output is as above but without the `type` property.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.Version;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonCreator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonSubTypes;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonSubTypes.Type;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonTypeInfo;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonTypeInfo.As;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonTypeInfo.Id;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.Module;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.Module.SetupContext;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ResolvableSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleModule;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleSerializers;

public class JacksonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Module m = new SimpleModule("TestModule", new Version(1,0,0,"")) {
            @Override
            public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
                super.setupModule(context);
                context.setMixInAnnotations(Animal.class, AnimalMixIn.class);

                SimpleSerializers serializers = new SimpleSerializers();
                serializers.addSerializer(Zoo.class, new ZooSerializer());
                context.addSerializers(serializers);
            }
        };
        mapper.registerModule(m);
        mapper.configure(Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

        Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
        List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        animals.add(new Dog("Spike", "mutt", "red"));
        animals.add(new Cat("Fluffy", "spider ring"));
        zoo.animals = animals;

        System.out.println(zoo);
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(zoo);
        System.out.println(json);
    }

    static class Zoo {
        public Collection<Animal> animals = Collections.EMPTY_SET;

        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Zoo: { ");
            for (Animal animal : animals)
                sb.append(animal.toString()).append(" , ");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    static class ZooSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Zoo> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Zoo t, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            Map<Object, Animal> animalMap = new HashMap<Object, Animal>();
            for (Animal a : t.animals)
                animalMap.put(a.getName(), a);
            jg.writeObject(animalMap);
        }
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(
            use=Id.NAME,
            include=As.PROPERTY,
            property="type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(value=Cat.class,name="cat"),
        @Type(value=Dog.class,name="dog")
    })
    static abstract class AnimalMixIn {
    }

    static interface Animal<T> {
        T getName();
    }

    static abstract class AbstractAnimal<T> implements Animal<T> {
        private final T name;

        protected AbstractAnimal(T name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public T getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    static class Dog extends AbstractAnimal<String> {
        private final String breed;
        private final String leashColor;

        @JsonCreator
        public Dog(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("breed") String breed,
                   @JsonProperty("leashColor") String leashColor)
        {
            super(name);
            this.breed = breed;
            this.leashColor = leashColor;
        }

        public String getBreed() {
            return breed;
        }

        public String getLeashColor() {
            return leashColor;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Dog{" + "name=" + getName() + ", breed=" + breed + ", leashColor=" + leashColor + "}";
        }
    }

    static class Cat extends AbstractAnimal<String> {
        private final String favoriteToy;

        @JsonCreator
        public Cat(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("favoriteToy") String favoriteToy) {
            super(name);
            this.favoriteToy = favoriteToy;
        }

        public String getFavoriteToy() {
            return favoriteToy;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Cat{" + "name=" + getName() + ", favoriteToy=" + favoriteToy + '}';
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT: Adding additional test cases that may clarify the problem

After reading some more questions about similar issues, I decided to try modifying my custom serializer to narrow down where the problem is.  I discovered that adding my `Animal` objects to any generically typed Collection (`List<Animal>` and `Map<Object, Animal>` were tested), the type information was not serialized.  However, when serializing an `Animal[]`, the type information was included.  Unfortunately, while I can vary that behavior in the test code, I need my production code to serialize a `Map` with polymorphic values.

Changing the custom `ZooSerializer.serialize()` method to the following does output type information, but loses the `Map` semantics I need:

```
public void serialize(...) {
    Animal[] animals = t.animals.toArray(new Animal[0]);
    jg.writeObject(animals);
}
```

Comment: I agree that it seems reasonable that the `JsonGenerator` in the custom serializer would use the `AnimalMixIn` config.  Hopefully, StaxMan will chime in.

Comment: Largely borrowed from your blog, with a little bit added in to bring it closer to my actual code.  Thanks for the example, it helped get me started!

Comment: The problem with Java Collections is type erasure, when dealing with root values (and not property values, for which type is retained). Arrays retain content type (since it is not done using Generics).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a work-around, or maybe this is the appropriate solution.  Either way, it appears to be working.  Please let me know if there is a better way.  (I feel like there should be)

I defined an internal class that implements `Map<Object, Animal>` and provided an instance of that class to `JsonGenerator.writeObject()` instead of providing it a `Map`.  Jackson seems to be able to resolve the key and value types once the generic declarations are "hidden" and provides a non-null `TypeSerializer` to the created `MapSerializer`, resulting in the desired JSON output.

The following additions/modifications to the test source code generate the desired output.

```
private static class AnimalMap implements Map<Object, Animal> {
    private final Map<Object, Animal> map;

    public AnimalMap() {
        super();
        this.map = new HashMap<Object, Animal>();
    }

    // omitting delegation of all Map<> interface methods to this.map
}

static class ZooSerializer extends SerializerBase<Zoo> {
    public ZooSerializer() {
        super(Zoo.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Zoo t, JsonGenerator jg, SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException, JsonProcessing Exception {
        AnimalMap animals = new AnimalMap();
        for (Animal a : t.animals)
            animals.put(a.getName(), a);
        jg.writeObject(animals);
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct -- when sub-classing a Collection or Map, generic type information is stored in class file for super type (but NOT type itself!). This is one of possible work arounds -- another is using TypeReference / JavaType, which can express generic type signatures.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with type information, both `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` use alternate methods. So you probably want to have a look at `JsonSerializer.serializeWithType(...)` and/or `JsonDeserializer.deserializeWithType(...)`. These take care of handling details of how type identifier is handled; usually by delegating to actual `TypeSerializer` and `TypeDeserializer` which do the work, but need bit more information on actual JSON structure that serializer/deserializer will use (JSON Object for most POJOs, JSON Arrays for Lists, JSON Strings for Java Strings and so on -- but all these are configurable by custom serializers/deserializers).

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to how the `serializeWithType()` method gets called from within my current code.  My assumption was that the map serializer would call it when I called `JsonGenerator.writeObject(Map<Object, Animal>)` but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Should I be calling something other than `writeObject()` in the `serialize()` method?

Comment: Should I be using a custom instance of `Serializers` to register my custom `Serializer` with the `ObjectMapper` instead of a `SimplerSerializers`?

Comment: Update on the problem.  If I attempt to serialize an `Animal[]` in my custom serializer, the type is written correctly.  When putting the `Animal` objects into any type of generic collection, the type is left out.  How do I indicate to the `MapSerializer` or other Collection serializers that their keys and/or values are polymorphic types and should be serialized with `serializeWithType()` instead of `serialize()`?