# Convert Java List to a JSON Object keyed by attribute of the list objects using Jackson and Spring MVC 3.1

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-data-mongodb

In my Spring MVC 3.1 project, I have a model structure where one object has an attribute that is a list of child objects.  For example:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private List<Pet> pets;
}
```

then a Pet class like:

```
public class Pet {
    private String name;
    private String species;
}
```

With the default [Jackson HTTP Converter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJacksonJsonView.html) I can generate (and accept) Person objects that look like this:

```
{
 "name": "Tres",
 "pets": [ {
            "name": "Fido",
            "species": "Dog"
           },
           {
            "name": "Mittens",
            "species": "Cat"
         } ]
}
```

But what I would rather have it generate is:

```
{
 "name": "Tres",
 "pets": {
           "Fido": {
               "species": "Dog"
           },
           "Mittens": {
            "species": "Cat"
           }
         }
}
```

I know I could create my own view converter to manually convert my child objects to a Map, but if there is any existing Spring functionality for that, I would prefer to use it.  I have also tried investigating some of the Jackson annotations, but haven't yet found anything that meets my needs.

Also, I would prefer to not store the pets attribute as a Map in Person, because the 2 objects are stored in MongoDB and are in 2 different collections.  So I would need to perform the conversion on either the MongoDB read with a custom converter or on the output to the HTTP response with a custom converter.

I appreciate any help I can get on the View converter or the Mongo converter!

Comment: This is similar to a question already asked here:
[using-jacksons-jsontypeinfo-with-a-custom-serializer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140697/using-jacksons-jsontypeinfo-with-a-custom-serializer

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do...

```
public class Pet {
   private String name;
   private String species;
   public String getName()
   {
       return name;
   }
   public String getSpecies()
   {
       return species;
   }
}
```

Use the person's name as a key for the map and the value for the map is a list of pets

```
Map<String,List> peopleWithPets = new HashMap<String, List>();
peopleWithPets.put("Person Name", new ArrayList<Pet>());

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.putAll( peopleWithPets );
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will still yield something more like what I did not want.  It will result in a JSON object whose key is "Person Name" and value would be still a list of Pet objects.  What I would have the value of the "pets" key be another Map<String, Pet>.

Comment: so then what you want is a `Map<String, Map<String, Pet>>` (which seems conceptually confusing, but it's your app)

Comment: That would be the structure of the pets tag in the resulting object, but what I am hoping to find is a either a Jackson annotation such as @JsonTypeInfo.  But while trying to give an example, I found there's another question which involves this same idea.  Thanks for the help though; I will close this one as a repeat.